# Injective, Surjective or Bijective Functions

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, proof-verification

Determine if the function
$ f: ℝ → ℝ, f(x)= (1+x) / (3x-1)$ is:

a. Injective

b Surjective

c. Bijective

My answer:

a. $ f(x_{1}) = f(x_{2}) $

$ (1+x_{1})/(3x_{1} -1) = (1+x_{2})/(3x_{2} -1) $

$ (x_{1})/(3x_{1} -1) = (x_{2})/(3x_{2} -1) $

$ (x_{1})/(3x_{1}) = (x_{2})/(3x_{2}) $

$ (x_{1})/(x_{1}) = (x_{2})/(x_{2}) $

$ x_{1} = x_{2} $

Injective: Yes

b. $ f(x) = (1+x)/(3x-1) $

$ y = (1+x)/(3x-1) $

$ y(3x-1) = 1 + x $

$ y(3x) - y = 1 + x $

$ y(3x) - x = 1 + y $

$ 3x(y-1) = 1+  y $

$ 3x = (1+ y)/(y-1) $

Surjective: No

c. Bijective: No (Not both injective and surjective)

Is this correct?

Comment: The domain cannot be $\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 0):

As said in the comment: $\mathbb R$ cannot serve as domain of the function.

You should go for a function $\mathbb R-\{\frac13\}\to\mathbb R$ because the function is not defined for $x=\frac13$.

Observe that: $$\frac{1+x}{3x-1}=\frac13+\frac43\frac1{3x-1}$$ and that the second term cannot take value $0$ so that the function cannot take value $\frac13$. This shows that the function is not surjective.

Further to prove injectivity it is enough to prove injectivity on $\mathbb R-\{\frac13\}$ of the more simple function: $$x\mapsto\frac1{3x-1}$$